# How to Use PCA to Reduce Dimension on pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pca

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="classification")

    images = sc.binaryFiles("/home/kdh/lessImage/*.jpg")
    imagerdd = images.map(lambda (x,y) : (x, (np.asarray(Image.open(stio.StringIO(y)))) ))

    imagerdd1 = imagerdd.map(lambda (x,y) : (x, get_new_desc(y)))
    imageRddVal = imagerdd1.values()
    imageVal = imageRddVal.take(1)

    print imageVal
    print np.asarray(imageVal).shape

    rdd_val = imagerdd1.values()

    model = PCAmllib(1000).fit(rdd_val)
    transformed = model.transform(rdd_val)

    pcaValue = transformed.value()
    pcaOneVal = pcaValue.take(1)


    print pcaOneVal
```

my project is image feature-based classification
so, i have to use PCA to reduce dimension

```
 imagerdd1 = imagerdd.map(lambda (x,y) : (x, get_new_desc(y)))

 x : path 
 y : feature (the number of 3888)
```

but error POP!!!!!

error location is PCAmllib(1000).fit(rdd_val)
error

> 16/08/25 01:47:13 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
>   net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor.construct(ClassDictConstructor.java:23)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load_reduce(Unpickler.java:707)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.dispatch(Unpickler.java:175)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load(Unpickler.java:99)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.loads(Unpickler.java:112)
>       at org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.SerDe$$anonfun$pythonToJava$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:1507)
>       at org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.SerDe$$anonfun$pythonToJava$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:1506)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   16/08/25 01:47:14 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost): net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor.construct(ClassDictConstructor.java:23)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load_reduce(Unpickler.java:707)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.dispatch(Unpickler.java:175)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load(Unpickler.java:99)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.loads(Unpickler.java:112)
>       at org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.SerDe$$anonfun$pythonToJava$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:1507)
>       at org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.SerDe$$anonfun$pythonToJava$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:1506)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 16/08/25 01:47:14 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
>   16/08/25 01:47:14 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
>   16/08/25 01:47:14 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 1
>   16/08/25 01:47:14 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (first at PCA.scala:42) failed in 44.752 s
>   16/08/25 01:47:14 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 failed: first at PCA.scala:42, took 44.807864 s
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/kdh/workspace/classification0/src/test.py", line 482, in 
>       model = PCAmllib(2).fit(rdd_val)
>     File "/home/kdh/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/mllib/feature.py", line 318, in fit
>       jmodel = callMLlibFunc("fitPCA", self.k, data)
>     File "/home/kdh/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 130, in callMLlibFunc
>       return callJavaFunc(sc, api, *args)
>     File "/home/kdh/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 123, in callJavaFunc
>       return _java2py(sc, func(*args))
>     File "/home/kdh/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in **call**
>     File "/home/kdh/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
>   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o28.fitPCA.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost): net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor.construct(ClassDictConstructor.java:23)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load_reduce(Unpickler.java:707)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.dispatch(Unpickler.java:175)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load(Unpickler.java:99)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.loads(Unpickler.java:112)
>       at org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.SerDe$$anonfun$pythonToJava$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:1507)
>       at org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.SerDe$$anonfun$pythonToJava$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:1506)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Driver stacktrace:
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
>       at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1302)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1342)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1341)
>       at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.PCA.fit(PCA.scala:42)
>       at org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.PythonMLLibAPI.fitPCA(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:634)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
>       at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
>       at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
>       at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
>       at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>       at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor.construct(ClassDictConstructor.java:23)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load_reduce(Unpickler.java:707)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.dispatch(Unpickler.java:175)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load(Unpickler.java:99)
>       at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.loads(Unpickler.java:112)
>       at org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.SerDe$$anonfun$pythonToJava$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:1507)
>       at org.apache.spark.mllib.api.python.SerDe$$anonfun$pythonToJava$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(PythonMLLibAPI.scala:1506)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       ... 1 more

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: Are you, by chance, mixing up the syntax with the pyspark.ml.feature PCA with the mllib library? I think the method from mllib is computePrincipalComponents while the method from ml is PCA.